# PyDev Eclipse Python interpreters Error: stdlib not found

Tags: python, eclipse, pathinfo

Errors with PyDev.

I keep getting the following error:

"Error: Python stdlib not found

It seems that the Python /Lib folder (which contains the standard library) was not found /selected during the instal process.

This folder (which contains files such as threading.py and traceback.py) is required for PyDev to function properly (and it must contain the actual source files, not only .pyc files) ..."

**I use Windows 7**.

I've been searching for hours on end on this solution, trying to resolve this problem yet I've come to no solution...

-Tried putting in all the files in Lib but no result.

I also looked under sys.path and to me it looked as if it was in the correct place, here's a pic: ( Can't post pics since I'm new to forums, but here's a typer copy of the code)

-When I did **sys.path** it came up with this:
['C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib', 'C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip', 'C:\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\Python27\lib', 'C:\Python27\lib\plat-win', 'C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\Python27', 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages']

Also, here's this:

> > > os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 423, in **getitem**
    return self.data[key.upper()]
KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'

I've also tried the following CMD command: set PYTHONPATH C:\PYthon27\lib;C:\MyPythonlib
However it states it is **not defined.**

Now I'm confused. Is the path not in the correct place? If so, how can I make the changes and what are those changes? I still think the path is incorrect though I'm in a loss in how to fix this issue.

I'll be honest, I'm a total noob when it comes to programming languages and such, so this is all new to me. Tho, I've been on this for countless hours now with no solution... I've been researching articles after articles on this, and would really appreciated if someone could please give me a nice clean answer to help direct me in the right path :).

Thanks

Comment: The correct syntax for setting an environment variable on Windows is `set PYTHONPATH=C:\PYthon27\lib;C:\MyPythonlib`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when configuring the interpreter in PyDev, take a look at the folders you're selecting and check if you actually have the .py files on those (instead of just .pyc files)... PyDev checks if the standard library is available by checking if threading.py (and some other folders) are available on one of those folders (if you only have .pyc files, you may have to get a Python version from python.org which actually has .py files and not only .pyc files).